# How to access a remote virtual machine desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, virtualhost

I 've a virtual machine running ubuntu operating machine on the server, whose ip address is say xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. My local machine also runs ubuntu.

How can I access the remote machine's desktop from my local machine?
I already tried using remmina remote desktop client, but it's not working if I try to display the desktop, but does work to access just the terminal of the remote machine.

A simple solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the VM definitely a desktop installation rather than a server one?

Comment: vm is there on a server

Comment: That's not what I was asking, if the VM is an installation of Ubuntu Server edition, it will not have a desktop environment.

Comment: oh, sorry I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install and run the dektop sharing server on your virtual machine. Remmina might (i'm not sure if it is done that way) ssh to provide you access to the terminal remotely, but it will not show you the desktop unless you install and configure the remote desktop server - for example Vino.

You may want to have a look at Ubuntu Help here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers